# Web API Parameter Binding

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Request Payload does not get coverted to Custom Request Object.

payload

```
appl5=MC~IC&i~PhoneToPhone~inet_ptt_cb_phn~1=440&inet_ptt_cb_phn~3=7406&i~PhoneToPhone~inet_ptt_cb_delay=0&BeenHere=TRUE
```

It has ~ in keyvalue pair (both in key and value).

I have a Request Model that convert the input params to avalid Object.

Note: I cannot have ~ in my C# property.  ( Can i ? )

My Post method has the following code

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(ClientRequest request)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;

        try
        {
            ProcessRequest target = new ProcessRequest(myRepository, myService);
            response = target.Process(request);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, exception.Message);
            //TODO : Log Exception.
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Model

```
public class ClientRequest      
{
        public string Appl5 { get; set; }
        public string I_PhoneToPhone_inet_ptt_cb_phn_1 { get; set; }
        public string I_PhoneToPhone_inet_ptt_cb_delay { get; set; }
        public string Inet_ptt_cb_phn_3 { get; set; }
        public string BeenHere { get; set; }
```

}

My request object does not have the values for   i~PhoneToPhone~inet_ptt_cb_phn~1, its null.

My understanding was the model binding is not happening because  the payload key does not match 
with my model (ClientRequest) which does not have ~ for i~PhoneToPhone~inet_ptt_cb_phn~1 
in stead i have i_PhoneToPhone_inet_ptt_cb_phn_1

Should i use Custom Binding ?

Comment: I personally would just change my models property names to camel case and avoid the headache.

Comment: I don't think changing Camel case would work.

Comment: At last, i can get it work by adding Costom Binder

Answer (score 0):

At last, Added Custom Model binder

public class PostParameterModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {

```
    bool IModelBinder.BindModel(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        bool success = false;

        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(ClientRequest))
        {
            NameValueCollection postData = null;

            postData = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;

            ClientRequest clientrequest = MapPostDataToRequest(postData);

            bindingContext.Model = clientrequest;

            success = true;
        }

        return success;
    }
 }
```

}